# How to make a button toggle a led?

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, python-3, pigpio

I have some code which turns an led on when I hold the button. But only when I am pressing it. Could somebody help me so when I press the button then the light stays on and if I press it again the led turns off?

Here is my code -

```
#button.py
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

sleepTime = .1

#GPIO Pin of the conponent
lightPin = 4
buttonPin = 17

GPIO.setup(lightPin, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(buttonPin, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.output(lightPin, False)

try:
    while True:
        GPIO.output(lightPin, not GPIO.input(buttonPin))
        sleep(.1)

finally:
    GPIO.output(lightPin, False)
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways of storing state which could be applied to your code, but running a continuous loop is poor programming.

The following example is one way of doing this which doesn't involve continuous polling.

https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/physical-computing/9

You could do similar with `RPi.GPIO`

Answer (score 0):

This is taken from another similar post; I'm on my mobile replying so I cant post the URL easily, but in essence,

> You can't read an output. Just store the state of the pin in a
>   variable.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

LED = 17
ledState = False

GPIO.setup(LED,GPIO.OUT)

ledState = not ledState
GPIO.output(LED, ledState)
```

Hope that helps.

Will try to post link later when I get time.

Comment: In fact you **CAN** read the state of an output - it will return the last value written.